# Send HTTP POST request in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpwebrequest, httprequest

How can I make an HTTP [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request and send data in the body?

Answer (score 2701, accepted):

There are several ways to perform HTTP [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) and [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) requests:

---

### Method A: HttpClient (Preferred)

Available in: .NET Framework 4.5+, .NET Standard 1.1+, and .NET Core 1.0+.

It is currently the preferred approach, and is asynchronous and high performance. Use the built-in version in most cases, but for very old platforms there is a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http).

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

#### Setup

[It is recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/) to instantiate one `HttpClient` for your application's lifetime and share it unless you have a specific reason not to.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

See [`HttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#what-is-httpclientfactory) for a [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) solution.

---

- POST

  ```
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "thing1", "hello" },
        { "thing2", "world" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  ```
- GET

  ```
    var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");
  ```

---

### Method B: Third-Party Libraries

***[RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp)***

- POST

  ```
     var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
     // client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
     var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}");
     request.AddParameter("thing1", "Hello");
     request.AddParameter("thing2", "world");
     request.AddHeader("header", "value");
     request.AddFile("file", path);
     var response = client.Post(request);
     var content = response.Content; // Raw content as string
     var response2 = client.Post<Person>(request);
     var name = response2.Data.Name;
  ```

***[Flurl.Http](https://flurl.dev/)***

It is a newer library sporting a [fluent API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), testing helpers, uses HttpClient under the hood, and is portable. It is available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http).

```
    using Flurl.Http;
```

---

- POST

  ```
    var responseString = await "http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx"
        .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { thing1 = "hello", thing2 = "world" })
        .ReceiveString();
  ```
- `GET`

  ```
    var responseString = await "http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx"
        .GetStringAsync();
  ```

---

### Method C: HttpWebRequest (not recommended for new work)

Available in: .NET Framework 1.1+, .NET Standard 2.0+, .NET Core 1.0+. In .NET Core, it is mostly for compatibility -- it wraps `HttpClient`, is less performant, and won't get new features.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;  // For class Encoding
using System.IO;    // For StreamReader
```

---

- POST

  ```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");

    var postData = "thing1=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("hello");
        postData += "&thing2=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("world");
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
  ```
- GET

  ```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
  ```

---

### Method D: WebClient (Not recommended for new work)

This is a wrapper around `HttpWebRequest`. [Compare with `HttpClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient/27737601#27737601).

Available in: .NET Framework 1.1+, NET Standard 2.0+, and .NET Core 2.0+.

In some circumstances (.NET Framework 4.5-4.8), if you need to do a HTTP request synchronously, `WebClient` can still be used.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
```

---

- POST

  ```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["thing1"] = "hello";
        values["thing2"] = "world";

        var response = client.UploadValues("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", values);

        var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
    }
  ```
- GET

  ```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var responseString = client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");
    }
  ```

Comment: How do you get the response from that?

Comment: @Lloyd: `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse();`

Comment: after the newStream is closed?

Comment: @Lloyd: If you are posting data to the stream (using the last three lines) it would make sense to check the response beforehand.

Comment: Why are you instantiating the ASCIIEncoding object instead of using the static `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`?

Comment: Why do you even use ASCII? What if someone needs an xml with UTF-8?

Comment: After so long time. I switched accepted answer to yours. As it is so much more detailed and I like that you shown old, obsolete methods.

Comment: I hate to beat a dead horse but you should do `response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: @DavidS. `response` should be a `HttpResponseMessage` - are you missing an `await` when calling `PostAsync`?

Comment: why did you say WebRequest and WebClient are legacy? MSDN doesn't say that they are deprecated or anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Hiep: They are not deprecated, there are just newer (and is most cases, better and more flexible) ways of making web requests. In my opinion, for simple, non-critical operations, the old ways are just fine - but it's up to you and whatever you are most comfortable with.

Comment: I know you said the preferred method is to instantiate a private readonly HttpClient but I think it is cleaner (and safer) to do a using statement instead. `using (var client = new HttpClient()) { }`

Comment: @GregA: It's not just me. The developers of `HttpClient` recommend one instantiation per application. In reality, it may be necessary to instantiate more, depending on what your application does. Just because it implements `IDisposable` does not mean you must put it in a `using` block.

Comment: `RestSharp` seems to be dead. Simply dead.

Comment: I wish this answer mentioned that it is possible to post raw `byte[]` content by substituting a [`ByteArrayContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193557%28v%3dvs.118%29) for the example's `FormUrlEncodedContent` and to read raw `byte[]` content with [`response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasbytearrayasync?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: What are advantages of HttpClient over HttpWebRequest and WebClient beyond asyncronism? Why the last two has become legacy?

Comment: @DouglasFerreira `HttpClient` and `WebClient` are higher-level wrappers around `HttpWebRequest`. The real question is when to use `HttpClient` as opposed to `WebClient` (or vice versa); this is best described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient/27737601#27737601.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete and useful answer. I learned a whole new way by reading it, because I've just started learning C # programming.

Comment: For method A - adding headers: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("name", "value");

Comment: HttpClient has properties like `BaseAddress` and handy methods like `CancelPendingRequests()`. "Instantiat[ing] one HttpClient for your application's lifetime" would be a very brave thing to do. I believe the intention is to create 1 HttpClient per use case or group of use cases attacking a same origin, in a singleton scoped service class or something like that. So there's a whole bunch of complexity you didn't ask for and likely don't need. 3 cheers for OO.

Comment: HttpClient is a bish to test since it has no interface https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests
You need all kinds of workarounds to write a unit test for it, just a consideration

Comment: @obesechicken13 You would typically mock the underlying handler instead of HttpClient itself (see `Moq.Contrib.HttpClient` package).

Comment: How to get the return URL generated by the POST using method A?

Answer (score 439):

Simple GET request

```
using System.Net;

...

using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var response = wb.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Simple POST request

```
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

...

using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["username"] = "myUser";
    data["password"] = "myPassword";

    var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
    string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

Comment: +1 For regular stuff POST it is great to have such short piece of code.

Comment: Tim - If you right click the literal that can't be resolved, you will find a Resolve context menu, which contains actions to add the Using statements for you.

If the Resolve context menu doesn't show up, it means you need to add references first.

Comment: I accepted your answer as good because it is much more simpler and clearer.

Comment: I would like to add that the response variable for the POST request is a byte array. In order to get the string response you just do Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response); (using System.Text)

Comment: @Sindre You can add it to the post.

Comment: Further, you can send a bit complex array $_POST['user'] as: data["user[username]"] = "myUsername"; data["user[password]"] = "myPassword";

Comment: Short and simple solution, I like it :)

Comment: [**Beware of WebClient as slow method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415443/system-net-webclient-unreasonably-slow)

Answer (score 80):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) has a sample.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestPostExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason it didnt work when i was sending large amount of data

Comment: @AnKing there is scope for that to be server limits rather than the client sending it.

Answer (score 37):

This is a complete working example of sending/receiving data in JSON format, I used [Visual Studio 2013 Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#2012%E2%80%932013_products) Edition:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();
        private static JavaScriptSerializer _Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run().Wait();
        }

        static async Task Run()
        {
            string url = "http://www.example.com/api/Customer";
            Customer cust = new Customer() { Name = "Example Customer", Address = "Some example address", Phone = "Some phone number" };
            var json = _Serializer.Serialize(cust);
            var response = await Request(HttpMethod.Post, url, json, new Dictionary<string, string>());
            string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            List<YourCustomClassModel> serializedResult = _Serializer.Deserialize<List<YourCustomClassModel>>(responseText);

            Console.WriteLine(responseText);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes an async HTTP Request
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pMethod">Those methods you know: GET, POST, HEAD, etc...</param>
        /// <param name="pUrl">Very predictable...</param>
        /// <param name="pJsonContent">String data to POST on the server</param>
        /// <param name="pHeaders">If you use some kind of Authorization you should use this</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Request(HttpMethod pMethod, string pUrl, string pJsonContent, Dictionary<string, string> pHeaders)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
            httpRequestMessage.Method = pMethod;
            httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(pUrl);
            foreach (var head in pHeaders)
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(head.Key, head.Value);
            }
            switch (pMethod.Method)
            {
                case "POST":
                    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(pJsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    httpRequestMessage.Content = httpContent;
                    break;

            }

            return await _Client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

There are some really good answers on here. Let me post a different way to set your headers with the WebClient(). I will also show you how to set an API key.

```
        var client = new WebClient();
        string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + passWord));
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = $"Basic {credentials}";
        //If you have your data stored in an object serialize it into json to pass to the webclient with Newtonsoft's JsonConvert
        var encodedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newAccount);

        client.Headers.Add($"x-api-key:{ApiKey}");
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json");
        try
        {
            var response = client.UploadString($"{apiurl}", encodedJson);
            //if you have a model to deserialize the json into Newtonsoft will help bind the data to the model, this is an extremely useful trick for GET calls when you have a lot of data, you can strongly type a model and dump it into an instance of that class.
            Response response1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
```

Comment: Useful, thanks.  BTW It looks like the above technique for setting header-properties also works for  the older (deprecated?), HttpWebRequest approach. e.g. myReq.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = $"Basic {credentials}";

Answer (score 9):

Simple (one-liner, no error checking, no wait for response) solution I've found so far:

```
(new WebClient()).UploadStringAsync(new Uri(Address), dataString);‏
```

Use with caution!

Comment: That is quite bad. I don't recommend it as there is no error handling of any kind and debugging it is pain. Additionally there already is great answer to this question.

Comment: @Hooch others might be interested in this type of answers, even if it's not the best one.

Comment: Agreed, the only context in which this would be useful is code golfing and who golfs in C# ;)

Comment: I wrote this answer looking for http based logging solution, I guess some other people might find it usefull similarly.

Comment: why (at least in a real life application), a "no error checking", "no wait for response" instruction would be an applicable answer?

Answer (score 9):

If you like a [fluent API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) you can use [Tiny.RestClient](https://github.com/jgiacomini/Tiny.RestClient). It's available at [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tiny.RestClient/).

```
var client = new TinyRestClient(new HttpClient(), "http://MyAPI.com/api");
// POST
var city = new City() { Name = "Paris", Country = "France" };
// With content
var response = await client.PostRequest("City", city)
                           .ExecuteAsync<bool>();
```

Answer (score 9):

This solution uses nothing but standard .NET calls.

Tested:

- In use in an enterprise [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application. Uses async/await to avoid blocking the UI.
- Compatible with .NET 4.5+.
- Tested with no parameters (requires a "GET" behind the scenes).
- Tested with parameters (requires a "POST" behind the scenes).
- Tested with a standard web page such as Google.
- Tested with an internal Java-based web service.

Reference:

```
// Add a Reference to the assembly System.Web
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

private async Task<WebResponse> CallUri(string url, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    NameValueCollection rawParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string p in rawParameters.Keys)
    {
        parameters[p] = rawParameters[p];
    }

    var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = timeout };
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    if (parameters.Count == 0)
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    }
    else
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        string urlMinusParameters = uri.OriginalString.Split('?')[0]; // Parameters always follow the '?' symbol.
        response = await client.PostAsync(urlMinusParameters, content);
    }
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return new WebResponse(response.StatusCode, responseString);
}

private class WebResponse
{
    public WebResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string response)
    {
        this.HttpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        this.Response = response;
    }
    public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; }
    public string Response { get; }
}
```

To call with no parameters (uses a "GET" behind the scenes):

```
 var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
 WebResponse response = await this.CallUri("http://www.google.com/", timeout);
 if (response.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
     Console.Write(response.Response); // Print HTML.
 }
```

To call with parameters (uses a "POST" behind the scenes):

```
 var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
 WebResponse response = await this.CallUri("http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple", timeout);
 if (response.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
     Console.Write(response.Response); // Print HTML.
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

When using the **Windows.Web.Http** namespace, for POST instead of FormUrlEncodedContent, we write HttpFormUrlEncodedContent. Also the response is type of HttpResponseMessage. The rest is as [Evan Mulawski wrote down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/send-http-post-request-in-net/4015346#4015346).

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way of doing it:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
using (MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    form.Add(new StringContent(param1), "param1");
    form.Add(new StringContent(param2), "param2");
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, form))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return res;
    }
}
```

This way you can easily post a stream.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., how is it different? What are the pros and cons compared to some other answers? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63488415/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to POST a JSON message body, you could use the following. Assuming you have a class instance named *m*.

```
string jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m);

// Make POST call
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new
    HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "<url here>");
    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### *c# .Net*

```
    using System.Net.Http;
    
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

//POST    
    var values = new Object();
    values[0] = "Value1";
    values[2] = "Value2";
    values[n] = "ValueN";

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("URL", content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    

//GET
 var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("URL");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why is this not totally trivial? Doing the request is not and especially not dealing with the results. And it seems like there are some .NET bugs involved as well - see *[Bug in HttpClient.GetAsync should throw WebException, not TaskCanceledException](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8d87789-0ac9-4294-84a0-91c9fa27e353/bug-in-httpclientgetasync-should-throw-webexception-not-taskcanceledexception?forum=netfxnetcom)*

I ended up with this code:

```
static async Task<(bool Success, WebExceptionStatus WebExceptionStatus, HttpStatusCode? HttpStatusCode, string ResponseAsString)> HttpRequestAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string url, string postBuffer = null, CancellationTokenSource cts = null) {
    try {
        HttpResponseMessage resp = null;

        if (postBuffer is null) {
            resp = cts is null ? await httpClient.GetAsync(url) : await httpClient.GetAsync(url, cts.Token);

        } else {
            using (var httpContent = new StringContent(postBuffer)) {
                resp = cts is null ? await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent) : await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent, cts.Token);
            }
        }

        var respString = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode, WebExceptionStatus.Success, resp.StatusCode, respString);

    } catch (WebException ex) {
        WebExceptionStatus status = ex.Status;
        if (status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
            // Get HttpWebResponse so that you can check the HTTP status code.
            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response) {
                return (false, status, httpResponse.StatusCode, httpResponse.StatusDescription);
            }
        } else {
            return (false, status, null, ex.ToString());
        }

    // https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/
    } catch (TaskCanceledException ex) when (ex.InnerException is TimeoutException) {
        return (false, ex.ToString(), null, WebExceptionStatus.Timeout);

    } catch (TaskCanceledException ex) {
        return (false, ex.ToString(), null, WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return (false, WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError, null, ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

This will do a GET or POST depending on if `postBuffer` is null or not.

If *Success* is true, the response will then be in `ResponseAsString`.

If *Success* is false, you can check `WebExceptionStatus`, `HttpStatusCode` and `ResponseAsString` to try to see what went wrong.

Comment: I have been working on this for too long. Soooo far from trivial... in Java I need about 6-8 lines.

Comment: seems like things are getting better see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/

Answer (score 2):

This an example of an HTTPS web request. You can echo any results in a PHP script. Finally, a PHP echo string will be shown as an alert on the C# client side.

```csharp
string url = "https://mydomain.ir/test1.php";
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("username"), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("ali")));
postData.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("password"), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("123456789")));
StringContent myStringContent = new StringContent(postData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage message = client.PostAsync(url, myStringContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
string responseContent = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

DisplayAlert("Your Feedback", responseContent, "OK");
```

PHP server side:

```php
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] == "ali") {
    echo "Yes, hi Ali";
  }
  else {
    echo "No, where is Ali?";
  }
?>
```

The result will be "Yes, hi Ali".

This is for [Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin) Forms. For a C# .NET application, replace DisplayAlert with:

```
MessageBox.show(responseContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) you can make a POST call with the following code. Here I added some extra features to this code, so you can make your code work behind a proxy and with network credentials if any.

Also here I mention that you can change the encoding of your message.

```
HttpClient client = GetHttpClient(_config);

if (headers != null)
{
    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
    }
}

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

var result = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(body, encoding, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return new RequestResponse { severity = "Success", httpResponse = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, StatusCode = result.StatusCode };
}
else
{
    return new RequestResponse { severity = "failure", httpResponse = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, StatusCode = result.StatusCode };
}


public HttpClient GetHttpClient(IConfiguration _config)
{
    bool ProxyEnable = Convert.ToBoolean(_config["GlobalSettings:ProxyEnable"]);

    HttpClient client = null;
    if (!ProxyEnable)
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
    }
    else
    {
        string ProxyURL = _config["GlobalSettings:ProxyURL"];
        string ProxyUserName = _config["GlobalSettings:ProxyUserName"];
        string ProxyPassword = _config["GlobalSettings:ProxyPassword"];
        string[] ExceptionURL = _config["GlobalSettings:ExceptionURL"].Split(';');
        bool BypassProxyOnLocal = Convert.ToBoolean(_config["GlobalSettings:BypassProxyOnLocal"]);
        bool UseDefaultCredentials = Convert.ToBoolean(_config["GlobalSettings:UseDefaultCredentials"]);

        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy
        {
            Address = new Uri(ProxyURL),
            BypassProxyOnLocal = BypassProxyOnLocal,
            UseDefaultCredentials = UseDefaultCredentials,
            BypassList = ExceptionURL,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyUserName, ProxyPassword)
        };

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = proxy };
        client = new HttpClient(handler, true);
    }
    return client;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very nice different approaches given in answers. Sharing one more approach. This is tested with .Net 6.

1. Create a Proxy class for you API functionality
2. inject it or create instance of it when you want it.

Proxy class:

```
public class ApiProxy
    {
        private readonly string _baseUrl;
        public ApiProxy(string baseUrl)
        {
            _baseUrl = baseUrl;
        }

        public async Task<List<ResponseClass>> CallAPI(RequestClass requestObject)
        {
            try
            {

                string endpoint = $"{baseUrl}/your_api_endpoint";
                var _client = new HttpClient();
                string token = "your bearer token";
                string requestBodyString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestObject);

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(requestBodyString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint)
                };

                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                request.Headers.Add("correlationId", correlationId);

                var result = await _client.SendAsync(request);
                var content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseClass>>(content);
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Create instance of it or inject it via constructor injection when you need to call in Consumer class:

```
 await apiProxy.CallAPI(requestObject);
```

Happy coding !!

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I use in .NET 4.8 to make an HTTP POST request.
With this code, one can send multiple POST requests at a time *asynchronously*.

At the end of each request an event is raised. And also at the end of all requests another event is raised.

The one below is the core class:

```vbnet
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Timers
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports AeonLabs
Imports AeonLabs.Environment
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class HttpDataCore
    Public Property url As String
    Public Property state As New environmentVarsCore
    Public Property errorMessage As String = ""
    Public Property statusMessage As String
    Public Property threadCount As Integer = 25
    Public Property numberOfRetryAttempts = 5
    Public Property queue As List(Of _queue_data_struct)
    Public Property queueBWorker As Integer() ' has the size of threadCount
    Public Property queueLock As New Object
    Public Property retryAttempts As New _retry_attempts
    Public Property dataStatistics As List(Of _data_statistics)
    Public Property loadingCounter As Integer
    Public Property CompletionPercentage As Integer ' value range 0-100
    Public Property IsBusy As Boolean

    Public Structure _queue_data_struct
        Dim vars As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim filenameOrSavePath As String                  ' full address file name or full adress folder path
        Dim misc As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim status As Integer                             ' -1 - completed; 0- not sent yet; 1-already sent / processing
    End Structure

    Public Structure _retry_attempts
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim pattern As Integer
        Dim previousPattern As Integer
        Dim errorMessage As String
    End Structure

    Public Structure _data_statistics
        Dim filesize As Double
        Dim bytesSentReceived As Double
        Dim speed As Double
    End Structure

    Public WithEvents RestartQueueTimer As New Timers.Timer
    Public bwDataRequest() As BackgroundWorker

    Public Event requestCompleted(sender As Object, requestData As String) 'TODO add misc vars

    Private sendToQueue As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal Optional _state As environmentVarsCore = Nothing, ByVal Optional _url As String = "")
        queue = New List(Of _queue_data_struct)
        dataStatistics = New List(Of _data_statistics)
        loadingCounter = 0
        sendToQueue = False
        If _state IsNot Nothing AndAlso _url.Equals("") Then
            url = _state.ServerBaseAddr & _state.ApiServerAddrPath
        ElseIf Not _url.Equals("") Then
            url = _url
        Else
            Throw New System.Exception("Initialization err: state and url cannot be both null at same time")
        End If

        If _state IsNot Nothing Then
            state = _state
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub loadQueue(ByVal vars As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByVal Optional misc As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Nothing, ByVal Optional filenameOrSavePath As String = Nothing)
        Dim queueItem As New _queue_data_struct
        queueItem.vars = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        queueItem.misc = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        queueItem.vars = vars
        queueItem.status = 0
        queueItem.misc = misc
        queueItem.filenameOrSavePath = filenameOrSavePath
        queue.Add(queueItem)
    End Sub

    Public Sub clearQueue()
        loadingCounter = 0
        queue = New List(Of _queue_data_struct)
    End Sub

    Public Sub startRequest()
        If bwDataRequest(0) Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("You need to call initialze first")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'startSendQueue()
        IsBusy = True

        AddHandler RestartQueueTimer.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf QueueTimerTick)
        With RestartQueueTimer
            .Enabled = True
            .Interval = 500
            .Start()
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub QueueTimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        If QueuesToComplete(queue).Equals(0) And QueuesToSend(queue).Equals(0) Then
            RestartQueueTimer.Stop()
            queue = New List(Of _queue_data_struct)
            RaiseEvent requestCompleted(Me, Nothing)
            IsBusy = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If retryAttempts.counter >= numberOfRetryAttempts Then 'ToDo a retry number of attempts before quits
            Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(state.currentLang)
            Dim MsgBox As messageBoxForm
            MsgBox = New messageBoxForm(retryAttempts.errorMessage & ". " & My.Resources.strings.tryAgain & " ?", My.Resources.strings.question, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
            If MsgBox.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Yes Then
                Dim retry As _retry_attempts
                With retry
                    .counter = 0
                    .previousPattern = -1
                    .pattern = 0
                    .errorMessage = ""
                End With
                retryAttempts = retry
                startSendQueue()
            Else
                RestartQueueTimer.Stop()
                queue = New List(Of _queue_data_struct)
                RaiseEvent requestCompleted(Me, Nothing)
                IsBusy = False
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Not sendToQueue And QueuesToSend(queue) > 0 Then
            startSendQueue()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub startSendQueue()
        sendToQueue = True
        While QueuesToSend(queue) > 0
            For shtIndex = 0 To threadCount
                For i = 0 To queue.Count - 1
                    If Not bwDataRequest(shtIndex).IsBusy Then
                        SyncLock queueLock
                            If queue.ElementAt(i).status.Equals(0) Then
                                Dim data As New _queue_data_struct
                                data.vars = queue.ElementAt(i).vars
                                data.status = 1
                                data.misc = queue.ElementAt(i).misc
                                data.filenameOrSavePath = queue.ElementAt(i).filenameOrSavePath
                                queue(i) = data
                                queueBWorker(shtIndex) = i
                                dataStatistics(shtIndex) = (New _data_statistics)

                                bwDataRequest(shtIndex).RunWorkerAsync(queue(i))
                                Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
                            End If
                        End SyncLock
                    End If
                Next i
            Next shtIndex
        End While
        sendToQueue = False
    End Sub

    Public Function QueuesToSend(queue As List(Of _queue_data_struct)) As Integer
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To queue.Count - 1
            If queue(i).status.Equals(0) Then
                counter += 1
            End If
        Next i
        Return counter
    End Function

    Public Function QueuesToComplete(queue As List(Of _queue_data_struct)) As Integer
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To queue.Count - 1
            If queue(i).status.Equals(1) Then
                counter += 1
            End If
        Next i
        Return counter
    End Function

    Public Function QueuesMultiHash(queue As List(Of _queue_data_struct)) As Integer
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To queue.Count - 1
            If queue(i).status.Equals(1) Then
                counter += i
            End If
        Next i
        Return counter
    End Function

    Public Function IsBase64String(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        s = s.Trim()
        Return (s.Length Mod 4 = 0) AndAlso Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,3}$", RegexOptions.None)
    End Function

    '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Public Function ConvertDataToArray(key As String, fields As String(), response As String) As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
        If GetMessage(response).Equals("1001") Then
            Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(state.currentLang)
            errorMessage = "{'error':true,'message':'" & My.Resources.strings.errorNoRecordsFound & "'}"
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Try
            Dim jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(response)
            If jsonResult.ContainsKey(key) Then
                If Not jsonResult.Item(key).item(0).Count.Equals(fields.Length) Then
                    Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(state.currentLang)
                    errorMessage = "{'error':true,'message':'" & My.Resources.strings.JsonFieldsMismatch & ". table(" & key & "'}"
                    Return Nothing
                Else
                    Dim results = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
                    For k = 0 To fields.Length - 1
                        Dim fieldValues As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
                        For i = 0 To jsonResult.Item(key).Count - 1
                            fieldValues.Add(jsonResult.Item(key).item(i).item(k).ToString)
                        Next i
                        results.Add(fields(k), fieldValues)

                    Next k
                    Return results
                End If
            Else
                Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(state.currentLang)
                errorMessage = "{'error':true,'message':'" & My.Resources.strings.JsonkeyNotFound & " (" & key & "'}"
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            errorMessage = "{'error':true,'message':'" & ex.ToString & "'}"
            errorMessage = ex.ToString
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

the `AeonLabs.Envoriment` is a class with a collection or fields and properties.

And the one bellow is for making a POST request:

```vbnet
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports AeonLabs.Environment
Imports AeonLabs.Security

Public Class HttpDataPostData
    Inherits HttpDataCore

    Public Event updateProgress(sender As Object, misc As Dictionary(Of String, String))

    Public Event dataArrived(sender As Object, requestData As String, misc As Dictionary(Of String, String))

    Public Sub New(ByVal Optional _state As environmentVarsCore = Nothing, ByVal Optional _url As String = "")
        MyBase.New(_state, _url)
    End Sub

    Public Sub initialize(ByVal Optional _threadCount As Integer = 0)
        If Not _threadCount.Equals(0) Then
            threadCount = _threadCount
        End If

        ReDim bwDataRequest(threadCount)
        ReDim queueBWorker(threadCount)

        For shtIndex = 0 To threadCount
            dataStatistics.Add(New _data_statistics)

            bwDataRequest(shtIndex) = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
            bwDataRequest(shtIndex).WorkerReportsProgress = True
            bwDataRequest(shtIndex).WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

            AddHandler bwDataRequest(shtIndex).DoWork, AddressOf bwDataRequest_DoWork
            AddHandler bwDataRequest(shtIndex).RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bwDataRequest_RunWorkerCompleted
        Next shtIndex
        Dim retry As _retry_attempts
        With retry
            .counter = 0
            .previousPattern = -1
            .pattern = 0
            .errorMessage = ""
        End With
        retryAttempts = retry
    End Sub

    Private Sub bwDataRequest_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)

        ' Find out the Index of the bWorker that called this DoWork (could be cleaner, I know)
        Dim Y As Integer
        Dim Index As Integer = Nothing
        For Y = 0 To UBound(bwDataRequest)
            If sender.Equals(bwDataRequest(Y)) Then
                Index = Y
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Y

        Dim queue As _queue_data_struct
        queue = e.Argument

        Dim vars As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        vars = queue.vars

        'TODO translation need to be local
        If Not System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() Then
            Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(state.currentLang)
            e.Result = "{'error':true,'message':'" & My.Resources.strings.errorNoNetwork & "'}"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If vars Is Nothing Then
            e.Result = "{'error':true,'message':'missconfiguration vars'}"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Not vars.ContainsKey("id") Then
            vars.Add("id", state.userId)
        End If
        If Not vars.ContainsKey("pid") Then
            Dim appId As New FingerPrint
            vars.Add("pid", appId.Value)
        End If
        If Not vars.ContainsKey("language") Then
            vars.Add("language", state.currentLang)
        End If
        If Not vars.ContainsKey("origin") Then
            vars.Add("origin", state.softwareAccessMode)
        End If

        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim json As String = serializer.Serialize(vars)
        Dim encryption As New AesCipher(state)
        Dim encrypted As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encryption.encrypt(json))
        Dim PostData = "origin=" & state.softwareAccessMode & "&data=" & encrypted
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = ""
        Dim decrypted As String = ""

        request.Method = "POST"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", state.ApiHttpHeaderToken & "-" & state.softwareAccessMode)
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Try
            Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
            dataStream.Close()
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()
            reader.Close()
            dataStream.Close()
            response.Close()

            If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Accepted Or response.StatusCode = 200 Then
                If IsBase64String(responseFromServer) And Not responseFromServer.Equals("") Then
                    decrypted = encryption.decrypt((responseFromServer)).Replace("\'", "'")
                Else
                    Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(state.currentLang)
                    decrypted = "{'error':true,'encrypted':false,'message':'" & My.Resources.strings.contactingCommServer & " |" & responseFromServer & "|'}"
                End If
            Else
                Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(state.currentLang)
                decrypted = "{'error':true,'message':'" & My.Resources.strings.contactingCommServer & " (" & response.StatusCode & ")', 'statuscode':'" & response.StatusCode & "'}"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(state.currentLang)
            decrypted = "{'error':true,'message':'" & My.Resources.strings.contactingCommServer & " (" & ex.Message.ToString.Replace("'", "\'") & ")'}"
        End Try

        e.Result = decrypted.Replace("\'", "'")
    End Sub

    Private Sub bwDataRequest_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        ' Find out the Index of the bWorker that called this DoWork (could be cleaner, I know)
        Dim Y As Integer
        Dim Index As Integer = Nothing
        Dim data As New _queue_data_struct

        For Y = 0 To UBound(bwDataRequest)
            If sender.Equals(bwDataRequest(Y)) Then
                Index = Y
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Y

        If IsResponseOk(e.Result, "statuscode") Then
            data = New _queue_data_struct
            data = queue(queueBWorker(Index))
            data.status = 0 're queue the file
            SyncLock queueLock
                queue(queueBWorker(Index)) = data
            End SyncLock
            Dim errorMsg As String = GetMessage(e.Result)
            Dim retry As _retry_attempts
            With retry
                .counter = retryAttempts.counter
                .previousPattern = retryAttempts.previousPattern
                .pattern = retryAttempts.pattern
                .errorMessage = retryAttempts.errorMessage
            End With
            retry.errorMessage = If(retryAttempts.errorMessage.IndexOf(errorMsg) > -1, retryAttempts.errorMessage, retryAttempts.errorMessage & System.Environment.NewLine & errorMsg)

            retry.pattern = QueuesMultiHash(queue)
            If retry.previousPattern.Equals(retry.pattern) Then
                retry.counter += 1
            Else
                retry.counter = 1
                retry.previousPattern = retryAttempts.pattern
            End If

            retryAttempts = retry
            Exit Sub
        End If

        data = New _queue_data_struct
        data = queue(queueBWorker(Index))
        data.status = -1 'completed sucessfully status
        SyncLock queueLock
            queue(queueBWorker(Index)) = data
        End SyncLock

        loadingCounter += 1
        CompletionPercentage = (loadingCounter / queue.Count) * 100
        statusMessage = "Loading data from the cloud..."
        RaiseEvent updateProgress(Me, queue(queueBWorker(Index)).misc)
        RaiseEvent dataArrived(Me, e.Result, queue(queueBWorker(Index)).misc)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Aoenlabs.Security is a class for sending POST data encrypted using standard encryption algorithms.

Comment: I thought the original request was for C#

Comment: @KVN and you are correct. And you can convert easily my code into C# with a click of a button