# POST a HTML Form programmatically and display response

Tags: asp.net

I need to prepare ASP.NET site with form, fill form in code behind and then submit form to external site.

For example: user open www.myshop.com/pay.aspx, he does not have to fill anything because I fill form values in code behind and then user is automatically redirected to external site www.onlinepayments.com (with form data sent in POST).

I am able to make it work with regular hidden form and javascript that submits form but I dont like this way (user can see html).

So I use WebRequest class in code behind like in this answer: [How do you programmatically fill in a form and 'POST' a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857/how-do-you-programmatically-fill-in-a-form-and-post-a-web-page/26881#26881)

However in this answer Response is string (target site html). What can I do with this string? I want my user see target site (conent and URL) like it would happen with regular html POST.

Comment: Have you spoken to your online payment provider? Some have a server to server API, and will give you a URL to redirect to; some will allow for the cart to be signed prior to submission.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw -  it does not matter - online payment is just an example

Comment: So you mean you want them to fill out a form on one aspx page, and then when they hit Submit, you send the form values to another aspx page?

Comment: @LoveMeSomeCode - yes but I send them to external page (not aspx) and it works but exactly the way I want

Answer (score 0):

You receive the response html as string - you can do with it whatever you want (included render the html as is to your page, or you can custom the html before rendering it, etc...)

Comment: but then user will see my URL instead target site URL and their CSS paths might be relative etc. I want user to 'be' on that site as it happen with regular post (that browser make)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the target site works. If the resultant page is static you could simply `Response.Redirect` your user there after you have done the `POST` programatically. If the page is shown based on some session or cookie value you can't really redirect them there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in that case what you can do is change your FORM tag's action parameter. This will send a POST request to the other form with all the form variables in it. The new form will have dig out those POST variables and do what it needs with them