# How can I submit form in codebehind (C#)?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

I want to submit form from code behind (C#), like js - 
`$(formid).submit()`,
Is there any option like this?
I don't want any sophisticated solutions, just simple.
like the option in javascript.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a server side and client side. There are code that execute either side, C# executes in server side, form exists in client side. Form submission is done to start execution of server side code, if you are already in server side code, you dont have form or such, you are already doing what the form submission will result in.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857/how-do-you-programmatically-fill-in-a-form-and-post-a-web-page